# Why it directs me to a wrong url using codeigniter,

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a two controller function, Index function and generateReport function, when I click the export button it should direct me to this URI index.php/schoolScoreCardReport/generateReport, the problem is it directs me to this URI index.php/generateReport, i dont know why, here is my code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class schoolScoreCardReport extends PG_Controller {

public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();

}


public function index(){

            if(isset($_POST['Export'])){
                $this->generateReport();

            }

    $this->layout->view('report/index');
}

   public function generatePOMEDetailReport(){
     $this->layout->view('test/index');
}



}
```

Pls help me thankyou here is my html view for index function

```
  <table>
            <?php echo form_open('schoolScoreCardReport'); ?>
            <tr><td>
              <label>Region:</label>
              <select name="region_name" style="width:150px">
              <option value = "1">a</option>
              </select>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <input type="submit" id="btn_export"  value="Export" name="Export">
            </td></tr>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: show your html... especially export button related.

Comment: ive edited it sir

Comment: You are naming your classes and filenames wrong please read this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming and https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some routes going on to affect the requests, I believe the parameter sent to form_open() should be as follows...

```
<?php echo form_open('schoolScoreCardReport/generatePOMEDetailReport'); ?>
```

As generatePOMEDetailReport is the only function shown in your controller code above other than the index function.

If you really want it to call the index function so the IF $post check is done, try 'schoolScoreCardReport/index' for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string and its corresponding controller class/method in codeigniter. The segments in a URI normally follow this

example.com/class/function/id/

or you see this link :https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

in form_open  u need to follow this

```
<?php echo form_open('ControllerName/FunctionName'); ?>
```

in your case it is

```
 <table>
           <?php echo form_open('schoolScoreCardReport/generatePOMEDetailReport'); ?>
            <tr><td>
              <label>Region:</label>
              <select name="region_name" style="width:150px">
              <option value = "1">a</option>
              </select>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <input type="submit" id="btn_export"  value="Export" name="Export">
            </td></tr>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
     </table>
```